# My Android multi-threaded server does not work properly

Tags: android

I'm trying to set up a score update server on my Android device. Other phones can send scores and this server needs to show the visual results by updating the score of each client. Something like this:

[image]

Now my problems are:

1- The current multi-thread approach does not work. What is wrong with it?

2- How can I differentiate people when I receive them? Maybe by having a key-value/hashmap, and update the score corresponding to each IP/socket?

```
package course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class test extends Activity{
    // Start with some variables
    int i = 0;
    int people = 0;
    ArrayList<Bar> diagrams;

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private static Socket clientSocket;
    private static InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private static BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    private static String message;
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> map;
    boolean isDone=false;
    private TextView mXValueView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // set orientation
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        mXValueView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        map= new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        diagrams=new ArrayList<Bar>();
        // In onCreate method
        //      diagrams = new ArrayList<Bar>();
        // draw(0,0);
        //              connect_draw();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                connect_draw();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    // Register listener
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    // Unregister listener
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    //  void draw() {
    //      Bar d = new Bar();
    //      d.setColor(Color.parseColor("#118800"));
    //      d.setName("Test1");
    //      d.setValue(i);
    //      Bar d2 = new Bar();
    //      d2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFBB33"));
    //      d2.setName("Test2");
    //      d2.setValue(20);
    //      diagrams.add(d);
    //      diagrams.add(d2);
    //      BarGraph g = (BarGraph) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    //      g.setBars(diagrams);
    //  }

    void draw(int hash, int score){
        //the person was not existed: Create a new Bar
        if(!map.containsKey(hash) ){
            Bar d = new Bar();
            d.setColor(Color.rgb(new Random().nextInt(255), new Random().nextInt(255), new Random().nextInt(255)));
            d.setName(people++ +"");
            d.setValue((float)score);
            diagrams.add(d);
        }

        BarGraph g = (BarGraph)findViewById(R.id.graph);
        g.setBars(diagrams);
    }

    void connect_draw() {
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888); // Server socket
            Log.i("hello","hello: Server started. Listening to the port 8888");

            isDone=true;
            while (true) {
                clientSocket = serverSocket.accept(); // accept the client
                // connection
                inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(
                        clientSocket.getInputStream());
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); // get the client message
                message = bufferedReader.readLine();
                final int hash=clientSocket.getInetAddress().hashCode();
                //              i++;

                // draw(hash,Integer.parseInt(message));
                mXValueView.setText(message);
                Log.i("hello","hello: server received "+message+ " from "+hash);
                inputStreamReader.close();
                clientSocket.close();
            }
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("hello","hello: problem in reading message");
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the client code:

```
package com.lakj.comspace.simpletextclient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SlimpleTextClientActivity extends Activity {

    private Socket client;
    private PrintWriter printwriter;
    private EditText textField;
    private Button button;
    private String messsage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_slimple_text_client);

        textField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1); // reference to the text field
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1); // reference to the send button

        // Button press event listener
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                messsage = textField.getText().toString(); // get the text message on the text field
                textField.setText(""); // Reset the text field to blank
                SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
                sendMessageTask.execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

//10.73.172.214
                client = new Socket("10.73.172.214", 8888); // connect to the server
                printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                printwriter.write(messsage); // write the message to output stream

                printwriter.flush();
                printwriter.close();
                client.close(); // closing the connection

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.slimple_text_client, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

**UPDATE**: I've just added a simple textView, and noticed actually I'm not updating the UI view on another thread. How should I do that? Here is the warning stuff.

```
06-21 14:44:31.871: E/ACDB-LOADER(257): Error: ACDB audproc returned = -8
06-21 14:44:31.871: E/ACDB-LOADER(257): Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -8
06-21 14:44:31.951: W/InputMethodManagerService(575): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41e1aff0 (uid=10043 pid=2841)
06-21 14:44:35.004: E/ALSADevice(257): standby handle h 0x41597050
06-21 14:44:35.054: E/ALSADevice(257): Number of modifiers 0
06-21 14:44:35.054: E/ALSADevice(257): usecase_type is 0
06-21 14:44:35.895: W/ActivityManager(575): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/test.apk
06-21 14:44:35.895: W/ActivityManager(575): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/test.apk
06-21 14:44:36.115: W/PackageManager(575): Code path for pkg : course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues changing from /data/app/course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues-1.apk to /data/app/course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues-2.apk
06-21 14:44:36.115: W/PackageManager(575): Resource path for pkg : course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues changing from /data/app/course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues-1.apk to /data/app/course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues-2.apk
06-21 14:44:36.315: W/ResourceType(575): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
06-21 14:44:36.315: W/ResourceType(575): Failure getting entry for 0x7f060000 (t=5 e=0) in package 0 (error -75)
06-21 14:44:36.315: W/InputMethodManagerService(575): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin
06-21 14:44:36.365: W/RecognitionManagerService(575): no available voice recognition services found
06-21 14:44:36.796: W/ProcessStats(575): Skipping unknown process pid 2918
06-21 14:44:36.806: W/ProcessStats(575): Skipping unknown process pid 2923
06-21 14:44:36.806: W/ProcessStats(575): Skipping unknown process pid 2929
06-21 14:44:36.806: W/ProcessStats(575): Skipping unknown process pid 2933
06-21 14:44:37.216: E/Trace(2953): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-21 14:44:37.356: E/hello(2953): hello: problem in reading message
06-21 14:44:37.406: E/BufferQueue(254): [Starting course.examples.Sensors.ShowValues] drainQueueLocked: BufferQueue has been abandoned!
06-21 14:44:37.486: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(869): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
06-21 14:44:56.447: W/CNE(575): UNKOWN Unsolicited Event 5
06-21 14:44:59.410: E/StatusBar.NetworkController(662): updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
06-21 14:44:59.450: E/StatusBar.NetworkController(662): updateDataNetType NETWORK_TYPE_UNKNOWN
```

Comment: where are u starting your server ?

Comment: @r4jiv007 on a DragonBorad. That is similar to a phone; no display/touch though! Wondering why it does not work properly!

Comment: Interestingly, sometimes it works, but I have to click on the display to make it update the diagrams!

Comment: i meant where in the code !! :/

Comment: What do you mean? It starts from create() method.

Comment: @r4jiv007 also added the simple client

Comment: try to invalidate your view when it is updated

Comment: how should I do that?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot see what your client send. We see that your server reads one line and then closes the client. The server then increments variable i. The server does nothing with the info in the received line. Every client should place an identifier in that line followed by a score. The server would then decode identifier and score from that line. You are displaying a diagram but it is not yours?

Comment: Oh, the diagram is a sample diagram; similar to mine.

Comment: You know what? I need to update the UI (i.e. diagram) when I read something from the client. The diagrams just won't get updated.

Comment: You have to update the UI in the UI thread. You are not doing that. Your logcat with stacktraces will show you many things that go wrong. Please look in it and copy/paste a piece here.

Comment: Just added it. Actually I also updated my server code as well. Please help me on how to update UI as I found this is actually not done.

Comment: There are so many strange things in your logcat. For instance about the provider for test.apk and so on. And you are unclear about your tests. I don't know where to start. Where do you call `connect_draw()` now? You commented all out. Adapt your code please. Then what did you test with that TextView. Remove the last statement from `draw()` and write to the textview instead.

Comment: Just updated the text. Just forget about `draw()`, The little text view does not change! I'm trying to receive a value from socket to show.

Comment: Yes i understand that. But you are doing that in a thread. And not in the UI thread. You must have this mentioned in the logcat. Look for it. Do you see the hello hello received in the logcat? Place that statement before you set the textview as i think after trying to set the textview it crashes.